# How to get the number of columns in a dataset in python

Tags: python

A rookie question here.
I am trying to get the number of instances and the number of features in a dataset.
I am using pycharm
But I am getting an error:
(569, 31)
**[Problem 0-B]: Value should be 32, found 31**

```
def dimensions(dataset_id , dataset):
    dim = None
    num_inst = len(dataset)
    num_feat = len(dataset.columns)
    dim = (num_inst , num_feat)
    print(dim)

    return dim
```

Comment: You don't need the method anyways. ```print(dataset.shape) ``` is enough. Can you also add the detailed error log you are getting, as that will give us a better understanding of the error you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `dataset.shape` instead

```
def dimensions(dataset_id , dataset):
    return dataset.shape
```

Comment: Both solutions worked, although yours uses less code. There was an error in the read_data function, that handled the dataset, which caused this mismatch.